# How to turn off sentence case for bibstyle 'univie-ling'

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to use `biblatex` with the style `univie-ling`, which sets titles in sentence case automatically.
However, since I have been managing the casing of entries externally with JabRef for some time, I would like to generally keep bibstyles form setting the cases. Manually protecting all titles with `{}` is not an option because (a) it would also prevent JabRef from doing its thing and (b) my .bib is too big at this point.

As suggested in other posts (e.g [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430483/biblatex-changes-capitalisation-of-titles/430492#430492)), I tried switching that feature off using `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}`, but that did not change the output:

[image]

I am not very familiar with the syntax used for bibstyles, but what I need to overrule seems to be line 582 in `univie-ling.bbx`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,mvbook,inbook,collection,mvcollection,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}%
```

By commenting this line, I was able to achieve the desired result and leave the cases in the .bib-file untouched,

[image]

but I am trying to find a less invasive (and update-resistent) solution to this problem, other than creating my own style.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @BOOK{colu92,
        AUTHOR = {Christopher Columbus},
        TITLE = {How I Discovered {America}},
        YEAR = {1492},
        PUBLISHER = {Hispanic Press},
        ADDRESS = {Barcelona}
    }
    @ARTICLE{gree00,
        AUTHOR = {R. J. Green and U. P. Fred and W. P. Norbert},
        TITLE = {Things that Go Bump in the Night},
        YEAR = {1900},
        JOURNAL = {Psych. Today},
        VOLUME = {46},
        PAGES = {345-678}
    }
    @ARTICLE{phil99,
        AUTHOR = {T. P. Phillips},
        TITLE = {Possible Influence of the Magnetosphere on {American} History},
        YEAR = {1999},
        JOURNAL = {J. Oddball Res.},
        VOLUME = {98},
        PAGES = {1000-1003}
    }
    @ARTICLE{jame76,
        AUTHOR = {Kelly James and Harris, Jr., George and Wilby Wollops},
        TITLE = {{American} Independence and Magnetism},
        YEAR = {1776},
        JOURNAL = {Revol. Tracts},
        VOLUME = {32},
        PAGES = {34-55}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    style=univie-ling,%
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1} % should turn-off sentence casing
% but here this line doesn't change the result

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`univie-ling` uses type-specific field formats for sentence casing

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,mvbook,inbook,collection,mvcollection,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}%
```

(though this applies to almost all of the common entry types, except `@online`).

This means you need to counter this definition with a type-specific definition of your own

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,mvbook,inbook,collection,mvcollection,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished]{titlecase}{#1}%
```

This gets quite long and is possibly error-prone if `univie-ling` changes its type list.

A simpler alternative is to to use the starred version, which clears any type-specific settings first

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{#1}
```

For more details about type-specific formatting see [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=univie-ling,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{colu92,
  AUTHOR    = {Christopher Columbus},
  TITLE     = {How {I} Discovered {America}},
  YEAR      = {1492},
  PUBLISHER = {Hispanic Press},
  ADDRESS   = {Barcelona},
}
@ARTICLE{gree00,
  AUTHOR  = {R. J. Green and U. P. Fred and W. P. Norbert},
  TITLE   = {Things that Go Bump in the Night},
  YEAR    = {1900},
  JOURNAL = {Psych. Today},
  VOLUME  = {46},
  PAGES   = {345-678},
}
@ARTICLE{phil99,
  AUTHOR  = {T. P. Phillips},
  TITLE   = {Possible Influence of the Magnetosphere on {American} History},
  YEAR    = {1999},
  JOURNAL = {J. Oddball Res.},
  VOLUME  = {98},
  PAGES   = {1000-1003},
}
@ARTICLE{jame76,
  AUTHOR  = {Kelly James and Harris, Jr., George and Wilby Wollops},
  TITLE   = {{American} Independence and Magnetism},
  YEAR    = {1776},
  JOURNAL = {Revol. Tracts},
  VOLUME  = {32},
  PAGES   = {34-55},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: How I Discovered America.]